# Implementation of map - how to differ two ends of the map in iterator

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

**Iterator Implementation:**

```
 class iterator {
        private:
            Node<Pair>* _ptr = nullptr;
        public:

            iterator(Node<Pair>* ptr = nullptr) : _ptr(ptr) { }

            iterator(const iterator& itr) = default;

            ~iterator() = default;

            iterator& operator=(const iterator&) = default;

            iterator operator++(int) {
                Node<Pair> *cur = this->_ptr;
                if (this->_ptr) {
                    this->_ptr = _ptr->Next();
                }
                return cur;
            }

            iterator& operator++() {
                if (this->_ptr) {
                    this->_ptr = _ptr->Next();
                }
                return *this;
            }

            Pair& operator*() {
                if (!this->_ptr) {
                    throw MapElementNotFoundException();
                }
                return this->_ptr->Data();
            }

            bool operator==(const iterator& itr) const {
                if ((this->_ptr == nullptr && itr._ptr == nullptr) ||
                    (this->_ptr == itr._ptr)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

            friend bool operator!=(const iterator& itr1, const iterator& itr2) {///// non member
                return !(itr1 == itr2);
            }
        };
```

**Private of Map class:**

```
    Node<Pair> *_head;
    ValueType _default; /////////////////////////////////////////////////
    int _size;
```

**The methods begin and end:**

```
iterator begin() const{
            return iterator(this->_head);
        }

        iterator end() const{
            return iterator(nullptr); //////////////////////////////////////////////
        }
```

**How can I implement the iterator and end method so this would work:**

```
ASSERT_EQUALS(false, map9.end() == map7.end());
```

My goal is to implement the iterator in such way, in which I could implement correctly the operator == and != for iterators, as two iterators are identical if point to the same object in the same map, and different in other way.

**Edit: (Solution)**

```
private:
            Node<Pair>* _ptr/* = nullptr */;
            MtmMap<ValueType, KeyType, CompareFunction>* _map_ptr;
        public:

            iterator(Node<Pair>* ptr/* = nullptr*/,const MtmMap<ValueType, KeyType, CompareFunction> * mtm_ptr)
                : _ptr(ptr), _map_ptr(mtm_ptr){ }
```

Why the compiler says that there is here a const-correctnes problem. It say that it can't cast from const MtmMap * mtm_ptr to MtmMap * mtm_ptr.
But it just copy of the ptr.

Comment: Usually, it is not legal to even compare iterators from different containers. This is the case for all `std::` containers, and pointers into raw arrays. However, you could, for instance, store a pointer to the container itself within the iterator. Makes it a little more heavyweight, but allows you to check two iterators came from the same or different containers.

Comment: Or have the past-the-end iterator point to a sentinel node, possibly embedded in the container.

Comment: Could it be possible to handle it as in iterator I will save Node<Pair> ** ?

Comment: pointer to pointer to Pair and then only if they equal, it is the same map. That way, I wouldn't have to store pointer to the container, right ?

Comment: I see a few ways to do this:

* Extend your iterator to hold a pointer to the container. This would be trivial but makes your iterator bigger.
* Add a marker object at the end of your container (i.e. so that iterator::_ptr is never null). Then the two pointer values can never be the same. This may make your container bigger/more complex.
* Accept that you live in an imperfect world and don't handle this case (same as the STL).

Comment: waiting for answer for the option I suggested, why no Node<Pair> **, it is also unique. And the change in the code will be that I'll work with *_ptr, there will be stored nullptr or valid address, is it possible ?

Comment: Ok, I see. I can't have pointer to null. So. yes, storing a pointer to the container seems to be good enough and simple solution.

Comment: You *can* make sure `map9.end()` compares unequal to `map7.end()`, but you *shouldn't*. It is a bad idea to ever compare iterators into different containers, and thus it is a bad idea to make the result of such operation well-defined.